# Error in while loop in bash shell

Tags: unix

I am  beginner in UNIX. I am getting a silly error while writing a `while` loop.

Code:-

```
$ x=0
$ while [ $x -lt 10 ]
> do
> echo $x
> x=´echo "$x + 1" | bc´
> done;
```

I am getting the errors:-

```
0
bc´: command not found   
0
bc´: command not found
0
bc´: command not found
...
```

Can any body help me? I have no idea of shell programming.

Comment: please share complete program.

Comment: Consider using [`let`](http://ss64.com/bash/let.html) for arithmetic operations i.e. `while [ $x -lt 10 ]; do echo $x; let x=x+1; done`

Comment: @another.anon.coward As long as you're using bash, might as well use `(( ))` instead of let.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `x=´echo "$x + 1" | bc´` to increment `x` (which is wrong as pointed by danf), pls use the following

```
x=`expr $x + 1`
```

also note the spaces...`bash` is very picky

Here is the output --

```
xxxx@cse:~> x=5
xxxxx@cse:~> while [ $x -lt 10 ]; do echo $x; x=`expr $x + 1`; done;
5
6
7
8
9
```

You can use `bc` to get this to work, but it is better to use `expr`

```
xxxx@cse:~> x=5
xxxx@cse:~> while [ $x -lt 10 ]; do echo $x; x=`echo "$x + 1"|bc`; done;
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Or `x=$(($x + 1))`...or variants on that theme, including `: $((x++))`...I agree: built-in arithmetic would be better, but the `bc` code can be made to work too.

Comment: thanks for reply. but not working. while [ $x -lt 10 ]; do echo $x; x=´expr $x +1´; done;bash: [: too many arguments

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That will also work, but I personally like `expr`

Comment: @Bit_hunter You have your ticks wrong,,,it is the key below your `ESC` key, <backquotes> not '

Comment: @Bit_hunter I am guessing you are running from prompt, so your `x` is not getting initialized....before the `while`, add `x=0` or whatever initialization you want. Please see my answer, I added some examples for you. Also note that `expr $x +1` is WRONG, it has to be `expr $x + 1` (note the space before 1)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a parse error. You need a backquote. Change line to:

```
x=`echo "$x + 1" | bc`
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backticks to execute subcommands, use `$( cmd )`, this construct can be nested. Maybe you do the arithmetic with a pipe to bc for learning purposes, otherwise, the shell is capable of doing this in a number of ways

```
$((x+=1))
x=$((x+1))
$((++x))
$((x++))
```

HTH and kind regards

Comment: Just going to point out that the OP didn't say anything about bash, and your answer is composed entirely of bash-specific solutions.  While this will *probably* work, it's by no means guaranteed.

Comment: I can't check right now, but I'm quit sure zsh can do the same. And while you are right, of course, the probability that the OP is using bash is high :-)

Comment: I'm sure zsh can do it as well, because it's basically an extension of bash.  What I meant was, this is not POSIX compliant.  So this doesn't work in sh or dash.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using backticks.  Use ` (aka grave accent, aka U+0060) (found in the top-left on American keyboards) instead of ´ (aka acute accent, aka U+00B4).

For example, the following works fine:

```
x=0
while [ $x -lt 10 ]; do
  echo $x
  x=`echo "$x + 1" | bc`
done
```

The only difference between yours and mine are the ticks used to quote `echo "$x + 1" | bc`.

That being said, if you happen to be using bash (or a bash-like shell), there are much better ways of making the same loop.  For example:

```
x=0
while (( x++ < 10  )); do
  echo $x
done
```

This has the advantage of being both faster (because it doesn't call to outside programs) and easier to read (because it uses more traditional coding syntax).